# Возвращение к старому окну JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Суть в том, что есть кнопка ,которая активирует скрипт открытия нового окна с авторизаций в Discord для получения всех необходимых разрешений

```
<button onclick="get()">GetDS</button>
<script>
   function get() {
        let AuthWindow = window.open("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=77...", "Autorize", "scrollbars=yes, width=500, height=750,menubar=no);
   }
</script>
```

После чего при нажатии на кнопку Авторизовать происходит редирект на исходный сайт с токеном для авторизации , к примеру
`https://localhost:5001/Home/GetCode?code=txB2y6M5S2i80l4HQSW9F4unbU71iF`
Как можно произвести редирект из исходного окна ,с закрытием дополнительного `AuthWindow`
Прошу прощения за кривые формулировки.

[image: Новое окно]

Comment: Как я понял вы хотите получить токен который будет сгенерирован в URL окна авторизации, а после передать его в основную страницу и закрыть окно авторизации?

Comment: @RedWoolf Именно)

Comment: Ну закрыть окно можно после редиректа на ваш сайт, отдав в html `<script>Window.close()</script>`, а вот с передачей кода  в основное окно возможно получится использовать `window.postMessage()`, но я не уверен что выйдет, так как использовал его только с `<iframe>`. Для передачи кода вроде можно использовать вебсокеты.